# How to add repository for gnome-do in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 10.04 when I follow https://launchpad.net/~do-core/+archive/ppa.
I did:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:do-core/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
```

I get this error:

```
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages
  404  Not Found
Fetched 5,940B in 1s (3,577B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/do-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

Please tell me how can I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't.

If you try to filter the package list by series, you'll notice that Lucid isn't listed. The lucid/main packages don't exist (further evidence [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/do-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/)). There's a message on the [Gnome-Do mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/gnome-do) that says the developers are in the middle of rewriting it. You can try building it from source.